# Question based on geomerical properties of complex number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let $z$  and $w$  be two complex numbers such that $\left| z\right| \leq 1$, $\left| w\right| \leq 1$ and $\left| z+iw\right|= \left| z- i\bar{w} \right|=2$, then z equals

(A) $1$ or $i$

(B) $i$ or $-i$

(C) $1$ or $-1$

(D) $i$ or $-1$

**My Approach :**

$ \left| z+iw\right|= \left| z- i\bar{w} \right|$

$ \left| z-(-iw)\right|= \left| z- i\bar{w} \right|$

Therefore $z$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of the line joining $-iw$ and $i\bar{w}$.

$i\bar{w}$ is the mirror image of $iw$ in the x-axis.

After this, I don't understand what to do next.

**A hint will be of great help.**

Thanks in advance.

**Final Answer:** 
(C) $1$ or $-1$

Comment: Can you please explain me the reason for downvote sir? I'll be highly grateful to you for that. Thanks for your precious time to see this question.

Comment: Snobbery, that's likely the reason.

Comment: You have found that $z$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $-iw$ and $i\overline{w}$, and that the two of them are symmetric with respect to the $X$-axis. Therefore, the $X$-axis is their perpendicular bisector. Hence $z$ is on the $X$-axis; $z$ must be real.

Comment: @Mlazhinka Got it, Thanks a lot.